# Background app screenshot showing wrong orientation after double tapping home

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, taskbar

My app is Landscape only, and all is fine until it's sent to the background.

When my app is in the background, and I double-tap Home to bring up the task switcher, my app screenshot is displayed as Portrait. The screenshot was taken as Landscape, but is skewed to display as Portrait.

Note, I am upgrading my app from a previous version to Xcode 6, iOS 7/8. My app doesn't do any background processing.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm assuming I'm missing a setting or call somewhere since I've searched for this issue with no luck. If you find this to be a duplicate then please point me to the appropriate article.

Comment: @Iganton Does your App launch in Landscape orientation?

Comment: Yes, it launches and runs in Landscape only. Problem is when I tap the home button to "minimize" the app, then double tap the home button, the image in the task list is distorted into Portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My AdBannerView was causing the app screenshot to display in Portrait.
To resolve, I removed the banner from its super view on resign active.

Answer (score 3):

If your App is being launched in Landscape Orientation, You can try out launching it in Portrait & See if it happens.

As [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) States:

> At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a
>   portrait orientation. After the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the app
>   uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate
>   the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

Let me know what result you get trying this.

Comment: Other than the proper "Default" launch image (which I see when the app starts), is there some other way to "set up the interface in a portrait orientation". The initial RootViewController xib is specifically Landscape in IB, as are all other ViewControllers.